# Android Alert.Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I am struggling with Alert.Dialog. The thing is I need to create alert dialog with two input fields. One for item and another one for a price(which should be saved as int so I can summarize it later on).

So far I just managed to add items into list. And this is the piece of code responsible for it.

```
if (id == R.id.action_add)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Item");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        builder.setView(input);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                shoppingList.add(input.getText().toString());
                Collections.sort(shoppingList);
                storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return true;

    }
```

[This is how list looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fbh2.png)

- What I basically need is to add price to each item

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please ask a specific question like: "How can I add two input fields to a Alert.Dialog". Add the specific problem to the question, do you get an error? Don't know how to do it? Simply doesn't show anything? The people could help you a lot better with a concrete description of your problem. It's not the idea to adapt speficic code samples, the idea is to answer general questions so that other people can us it if they have the same problem. Please edit the questiona and be more specific where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand this correctly, you just need another EditText for the price

Something like this maybe?

```
...
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
final EditText price = new EditText(this);
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
price.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | IntputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
layout.addView(input);
layout.addView(price);
builder.setView(layout);
...
```

and in the onClick methode:

```
shoppingList.add(input.getText().toString() + " " + price.getText().toString());
```

Wasn't able to test it!

Comment: anyway could you give me a tip how to set a title for price field as well? Because when I do builder.setTitle("Add price"); it overwrite builder.setTitle("Add Item");

Comment: Isn't it possible to set just one title?

Comment: You could set the title to "Add item and price"

Comment: Unfortunately its possible to add just one. But I found a way around it and set hint for each field, so mission accomplished! thank you :))